# Microbrewery in Prague

Tags: breweries, micropub, pilsener

Czech is known for its Pilsen Pilsner but is there any special beer from the Prague capital?

Are there any craft/microbrewery in Prague?

Any suggestions to pub that serves good craft Czech brews?

Comment: I'd like to know the same!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am from Prague and sure, there are many microbreweries here.

It sure depends what part of city you are in, but here are some of my personal tips (overall, the more to the city center, the more expensive it is)

- City center - [Novomestsky pivovar](http://www.npivovar.cz/en/) - mostly for tourists I would say
- City center - [Pivovarsky dum](http://www.pivovarskydum.com/index/index/lang/en) - popular among locals as well
- City center - [U Fleku](http://en.ufleku.cz/) - very popular among tourists, nice atmosphere, not very cheap though
- North of Prague - [Pivovar U Bulovky](http://www.pivovarubulovky.cz/) - nice small brewery, locals mainly, near tram
- North of Prague - [Pivovar Kolčavka](http://www.pivovarkolcavka.cz/) - very nice brewery, good food, locals mainly, close to Palmovka Metro (underground)
- Southern Prague - [Jihomestsky pivovar](http://www.jihomestskypivovar.cz/) - again, very good beer and food, near Metro Háje
- Southern Prague - [Pivovar Hostivar](http://www.pivovar-hostivar.cz/) - one of the best gardens, nice beer and food, only about two years old, quite far from Metro (Hostivar or Haje)

And sure much more, but these are some of those I remember or have experienced myself.

You can ask for anything in particular, if you want.
Enjoy your stay in Prague :)
Zax

Answer (score 2):

Did some reading and found this site listing a number of microbreweries and beer gardens. [Pubs (Microbreweries)](http://www.praguebeergarden.com/pubs/category/microbreweries).

And this place seems cool, [Pivovar Hostivar](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g274707-d4793505-Reviews-Pivovar_Hostivar-Prague_Bohemia.html).

I'd love to see if other people know about more cool beer gardens.

Answer (score 1):

I was in Prague a month ago :-)

You absolutely must make a stop at the brewery at Strahov Monastery, [Klášterní Pivovar / Sv. Norbert](http://www.klasterni-pivovar.cz/index.php?process=34&languageID=2), in particular if you're a fan of hops. I wasn't enjoying the beer in Prague until a local directed me here for their excellent food (yes, they also have fantastic Czech dishes!) Here's a photo of the beers I had—

[image]

—from left to right, their Wheat Ale, Amber Ale, Dark Lager, Summer Red Ale (my favorite, but seasonal only), and IPA.

There's also [Prague Beer Museum](http://www.praguebeermuseum.com/en) near Old Town, a few blocks northeast of the famous astronomical clock tower. The name's a little misleading—it's just a beer garden with some bar food (not great). Most of the beers were lagers (pilsners, dark), with a few IPAs and other styles scattered about. I wasn't a huge fan of their selection, but perhaps I was being closed-minded. Relative to San Diego standards, their one porter on draft tasted more like barleywine (...unaged, blegh), their one pale ale tasted skunky to me, and their IPAs tasted like they were afraid to use too much hops :-) If you check it out and have a different experience, please let me know.

And also don't hesitate to self-answer your question after your travels, especially if you've found breweries or pubs not mentioned here.

Below, the first of 3 flights I ordered at Prague Beer Museum.

[image]